# I want to center my popup text so it is in the middle... But I can't?

Tags: html

The title says it all. I need help with aligning the popup text, first time posting here as I search and tried but couldn't find any solution :(

I'm made the popup appear when I press a button but I can't align POPUP ARROW with the button.

I don't know what more I can say about this but I can't submit it as I must say something more...

Note: I'm a learner not a professional programmer.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px; 
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center">

 
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
 <button class="button";">How to use?</button>
   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">1. Press "Insert Token" and insert the tokens.txt</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought the index is php so might be relatable.

Comment: Perhaps: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to bring in center ? Is it the whole pop up or just the text inside popup ??

Comment: The whole popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z94o3qam/) is what you're looking for?

Your issue was with the `margin-left` on `.popup .popuptext`. You had it set to `-80px`, it needs to be half of the width.

**Edit**

I have updated the Fiddle to include the changes suggested by @Atul in the comment below. `margin-left: -250px` has been removed and replaced with `transform: translateX(-50%)`.

Comment: Hi BalckSmith, Just saw you fiddle, Although you have applied the right logic but this can be improved, So here the popup width is fixed and you have applied margin in minus exact = to half of its width, that's the logic, but achieve this by transform: translateX(-50%); and it will never break even after the width of the pop changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do One thing get it in center through css

```
.popup-text{
     visibility: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px; 
     background-color: #555;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: left;
     border-radius: 6px;
     padding: 8px;
     position: absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
     z-index: 1;
}
```

It will position your popuptext in center vertically and horizontally as well. 
if you just want it center vertically so change last 3 line code with this code:

```
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%); // You can event use margin-left:-250px b'cause you have fix 500px.
```